# How to call private member function by using a pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointer-to-member

Rookie question:

So there is this class

```
class A
{
private:
    void error(void);
public:
    void callError(void);
};
```

And I would like to call error from callError using a pointer.

I can achieve calling a public function from main using a pointer.

```
int main(void)
{
    void (A::*abc)(void) = &A::callError;
    A test;

    (test.*abc)();
    return (0);
}
```

However, I cannot find a way how to call error function from callError using a pointer. Any tips? :)

Comment: It's private. You can change the visibility. You can probably call it from a lambda that's created by another method of the class.

Comment: From inside `A::callError` you might do equivalent code...

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? Is it for unit tests? If the latter you can use some template trickery so as to avoid polluting the code you're testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a public method to your class that returns a pointer to the private function:

```
class A
{
private:
    void error(void);
public:
    void callError(void);

    auto get_error_ptr() {
        return &A::error;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    void (A::*abc)(void) = &A::callError;
    A test;

    (test.*abc)();

    void (A::*error_ptr)(void) = test.get_error_ptr();
    (test.*error_ptr)();

    return (0);
}
```

But I wouldn't suggest actually using this kind of code in a real application, it is extremely confusing and error-prone.